# Java, Selenium, and Method.invoke(): Getting NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nosuchmethoderror

**Goal**:  Create my own method that calls the Selenium method passed into it and repeats that method a specified number of times.

**Problem**: No matter what I try, the following code ALWAYS results in:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.sendKeys()

**Discussion**: As far as I know sendKeys() exists as a method within/of org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver

Problem code:

Method objTest = WebDriver.class.getMethod(strMethod, CharSequence.class);

Where strMethod = sendKeys

**Code**

```
public void repeatAction(String strMethod, int numberOfTimes) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    int i = 0;
    Method objTest = WebDriver.class.getMethod(strMethod, CharSequence.class); // PROBLEM CODE - results in NoSuchMethodException
    while (i <= numberOfTimes) {
        objTest.invoke(strMethod, Keys.DOWN);  // I've hardcoded Keys.DOWN for now but will make this flexible later
        i++;
    }
}
```

I call my repeatAction() method in main():

```
AutocompleteDropdownPractice objADDP = new AutocompleteDropdownPractice();
objADDP.repeatAction("sendKeys", 5);     // Repeat Selenium WebDriver's sendKeys() 5 times
```

**Runtime Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2109)
at AutocompleteDropdownPractice.repeatKeysAction(AutocompleteDropdownPractice.java:17)
at AutocompleteDropdownPractice.main(AutocompleteDropdownPractice.java:45)
```

Any assistance as to what I'm doing incorrectly and how I should be doing it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [Selenium API](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) you'll see that there isn't any method of `WebDriver` class as sendKeys() and that is the very reason why you are getting the NoSuchMethodException.

I think you were looking for the `org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)` method, which in your case you could use it as follows:

```
Method objTest = WebElement.class.getMethod(strMethod, CharSequence[].class);
```

I used the array version `CharSequence[].class` instead of `CharSequence.class` because the `sendKeys` method accepts an array of `CharSequence.class` which can be clearly seen in the [API docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html).

Answer (score 0):

**First**

If you refer to Java documentation you will see that [`invoke()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) takes two parameters:

1. Object that you invoke a method from (since you need the object to invoke non-static method)
2. Method arguments

These lines in your example:

```java
Method objTest = WebDriver.class.getMethod(strMethod, CharSequence.class);
objTest.invoke(strMethod, Keys.DOWN);
```

mean that you take method from `WebDriver` class and invoke it on `String` object which is incorrect.

**Second**

`sendKeys` method is declared in `WebElement` interface, not in `WebDriver`.

**Third**

What you are trying to do can be done with `Proxy` objects like shown here:

```java
public WebElement poxiedElement(String methodName, int times, WebElement element){
    return (WebElement) Proxy.newProxyInstance(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[]{WebElement.class}, new InvocationHandler() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object o, Method method, Object[] objects) throws Throwable {
            Object[] results = new Object[times];
            if(methodName.equals(method.getName())){
                for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
                    results[i] = method.invoke(element, objects);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
    });
}

void test(){
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."));
    poxiedElement("sendKeys", 5, element).sendKeys("blah");
}
```

**P.S.** - You should understand that a method can return a value. So calling any method several times might return several values. You have to consider this. In my example the method will return `array` of results.