# How to Automate Keypress "Space" and Arrow Keys in SAP using Java/AutoIT

Tags: java, selenium, sap-gui

I am using Java/AutoIT. I need to automate the keypress of "Space" and "Down_Arrow_Key" keys when automating in SAP. I have already done for "Enter" using the below code but I cannot find a way to automate for "Space" and "Down_Arrow_Key".

```
 public void pressEnter() {
    this.findElement("wnd[0]").invoke("sendVKey", 0);
}
```

So, my question is how to automate "Space" and "Down_Arrow_Key" keypresses when automating in SAP Desktop Application, when the element tracking is done via AutoIT(version 3)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why can't you use regular `.sendKeys()` method here.
With it you can simply send Space and Arrow Down keys as following:

```java
driver.findElement(By.id("your_element_id")).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
driver.findElement(By.id("your_element_id")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW-DOWN);
```

This can also be done with Actions:

```java
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
action.SendKeys(Keys.SPACE).Build().Perform();
action.SendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).Build().Perform();
```

But if you still have to use the `.invoke()` method looks like this should work:

```java
Method objTest = WebDriver.class.getMethod(strMethod, CharSequence.class);
objTest.invoke(strMethod, Keys.SPACE);
objTest.invoke(strMethod, Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64251166/java-selenium-and-method-invoke-getting-nosuchmethodexception)

Comment: yes, but the issue is that I am using AutoIT(version 3) for element tracking in the SAP Desktop Application, and therefore there is an issue with using the WebDriver and the regular .sendKeys() method. Would you be able to suggest a different solution maybe? Thank you in advance.